# Knowing child class overriding method of parent class without additional flag

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract

How do I know that a child class is overriding the method of its parent class? Currently I'm using boolean flag which is set false on the parent class, and when a child is overriding it, the child must set the flag. While it is working, I wonder if there is cleaner solution for this problem.

```
// The parent class
public Class_A
{
    protected bool _hasCheckData = false;
    public bool HasCheckData
    {
        get { return _hasCheckData; }
    }
    public abstract bool CheckData(File fileToCheck)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Lot's of children from class A, this is one of them
public Class_B : Class_A
{
    public override bool CheckData(File fileToCheck)
    {
        // the following line will be duplicated for all Class_A's children 
        // who implemented the checking of the file. How to avoid this?
        _hasCheckData = true; 

        // checking the file
        // and return the result
    }
}

public Class_C
{
    public void Test(File fileToCheck)
    {
       Class_B fileAbcChecker = new Class_B();
       if (fileAbcChecker.HasCheckData)
           fileAbcChecker.CheckData(fileToCheck);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a `CheckData()` that does nothing in Class_A (so it's not abstract anymore).  Then, in the relevant Class_B's, override this implementation.  In Class_C, remove the `if` statement.  In this way, `CheckData()` always gets called.  By default, it does nothing, unless the class wishes to do something with it.

Comment: Little note: Class_A must do something, that is returning false (or true)